# How to have only point in JqPlot rather than line

Tags: charts, jqplot

I am a newbie for JqPlot. Is it possible to plot only points without connecting them. As I don't want it to be a line chart. I just want scattered points on the graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `showLine` to `false`

```
seriesDefaults: {    
                  showLine:false
                }
```

`showLine` property is used ,whether to render the line segments or not

[**REFERENCE**](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series.showLine)

Comment: If you have more than one serie and want not to show line only for one of them you have to specify showLine: false to this particular serie and not to the seriesDefaults elements. [See here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php) : in the last example, only the second serie (the orange one) has his line not shown.